# Stripping characters from a Python string

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

```
v = "1 - 5 of 5"
```

I would like only the part after 'of' (5 in the above) and strip everything before 'of', including 'of'?

The problem is that the string is not fixed as in it could be '1-100 of 100', so I can't specify to strip everything off after the 10 or so characters. I need to search for 'of' then strip everything off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [19]: v[v.rfind('of')+2:]
Out[19]: ' 5'
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the [partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method is most readable for these cases.

```
string = "1 - 5 of 5"
first_part, middle, last_part = string.partition('of')

result = last_part.strip()
```

Answer (score 4):

[`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) was built for exactly this kind of problem:

```
In [2]: v = "1 - 5 of 5"

In [3]: v.partition('of')
Out[3]: ('1 - 5 ', 'of', ' 5')

In [4]: v.partition('of')[-1]
Out[4]: ' 5'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
p = find(v, "of")
```

gives you the position of "of" in v